# What Ubuntu tool records all desktop sounds?

Tags: gratis, linux, audio, ubuntu

In Ubuntu, I want to record everything that plays through my speakers.

If I were to play a movie and a YouTube video at the same time, the tool would record the mix of both.

It should output as an .ogg or a similarly popular format. It must be free, ideally open source.

Answer (score 11):

You can use **[ffmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/)**; it can record system audio from PulseAudio (which is the default sound server on Ubuntu), the command line should be similar to this :

```
ffmpeg -f alsa -i pulse -c:a libvorbis output.ogg
```

If it isn't installed on your system for whatever reason, here's a command to install it on an Ubuntu system (should also work on Debian, enter your password if asked) :

```
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
```

*Note: I didn't test this; feel free to comment or downvote if the above command does not work.*

Comment: The "ffmpeg" package doesn't exist in Ubuntu/Debian.

Comment: @Braiam: Related question: [Is FFmpeg missing from the official repositories in 14.04?](http://askubuntu.com/q/432542/82665)

Comment: @unor yeah? what that means? I know the package isn't available in Ubuntu repositories http://archive.ubuntu.com. The OP didn't say if the package should be obtained from third parties.